# How to hide image in PHP if there is no image set

Tags: php, html, css

How do I hide the image tag if there is no image present? Basically, I have an image gallery that has 4 images that can be set. However, if a product has 2 images how do I hide the other 2 image tags? What would be the best method to use?

```
<img src="/images/large/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;" class="hover-single"/>

  <div class="row">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Click on image to enlarge</p>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="/images/large2/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:80px; height:80px; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding-right: 5px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="/images/large3/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:80px; height:80px; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding-right: 5px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img src="/images/large4/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:80px; height:80px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
    </div>
  </div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="mySlides" style="display: block;">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="/images/large1/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="/images/large2/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="/images/large3/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="/images/large4/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&lt;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&gt;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="gallery cursor active" src="/images/large1/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%;" onclick="currentSlide(1)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="gallery cursor" src="/images/large2/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%;" onclick="currentSlide(2)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="gallery cursor" src="/images/large3/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%;" onclick="currentSlide(3)">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="gallery cursor" src="/images/large4/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%;" onclick="currentSlide(4)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with file_exists http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-exists.php

Comment: you need to check first that images are present or not when you are fetching data for product by using file_exists function if present then add into array otherwise else will not add image

Comment: @vikasvyas Thank you for the speedy response, I will try this method. Would you snippet me how the code would look please?

Answer (score 1):

Your modal-content code can be rewritten as below:

1. check if the image file exists or not
2. display the slide if the image file exists, do nothing if not.

   `for($i = 1; $i<=4; $i++) {
     $img_file = '/images/large'.$i.'/'.$prod_id.'.jpg';
     if(file_exists($img_file)) {
       $display = ($i == 1) ? ' block' : ' none';
       echo '<div class="mySlides" style="display:'.$display.';">';
       echo '  <div class="numbertext">'.$i.' / 4</div>';
       echo '  <img src="'.$img_file.'" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">';
       echo '</div>';
     }
   }`

The above code can be used to replace the following code section:

```
<div class="mySlides" style="display: block;">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
  <img src="/images/large1/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
  <img src="/images/large2/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
  <img src="/images/large3/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
</div>

<div class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
  <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
  <img src="/images/large4/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
</div>
```

Sure it is not the best way to check `file_exists` each time. This can be improved by means of storing the number of images for each product in your data set / database. Then just set a new variable such as `$img_num` to replace the 4 in the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I will test the answers and get back to you guys with a working solution. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div class="row">
    <p style="text-align:center;">Click on image to enlarge</p>
    <div class="column">
    <?php if(file_exists('/images/large2/'.$prod_id.'.jpg')){<?php>
      <img src="/images/large2/<?=$prod_id?>.jpg" style="width:80px; height:80px; border-right: 1px solid #cccccc; padding-right: 5px;" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"><?php } 
</php>
```

Comment: @NathanC you can see this method you can use but not on front end because it will take some time so better is that use when you are getting data inside query

Comment: @vikasvyas Thank you, I will test the answers and get back to you guys with a working solution. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible idea for your requirement :

```
$query = "here is your query";
$res   = "your query executed";
$imagearray = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
   if(file_exists(imagepath.$row["image"]))
   {
      $imagearray[$i] = $row["image"];
      $i++
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi their Brother ild flue did a good work, but we can enhance the code a bit more but making the fetching a bit more dynamic, I propose the code below,

1. scan the dir for existing folders(in that way u don't need to depend
   on the arbitrary number to indicate the folder
2. see that those paths with ur image exist or not
3. display the specified images and let the rest of the be discarded.

   ```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="display: block;">
   <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">×</span>
   <div class="modal-content">
   <?php
   $k=1;
   $dirs = array_filter(glob('images/*'), 'is_dir');
   foreach ( $dirs as $allLargeDir ){
       $imgPath=$allLargeDir."/".$prod_id.".jpg";
       if(file_exists($imgPath)){
      ?>
         <div class="mySlides" style="display: block;">
         <div class="numbertext"><?php echo $k++." / ".$n; ?></div>
           <img src="<?php echo $imgPath;?>" style="width:95%; height:95%; margin-left: 2.5%;">
        </div>
     <?php
     }
   }
   ?>
   ```